# Prove that the locus of the poles of tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ is the circle $x^2+y^2-ax=0$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Prove that the locus of the poles of tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ is the circle $x^2+y^2-ax=0$.

I have encountered this question from SL Loney.I have its solution in front of me,but i could not understand.

---

Let $(h,k)$ be the coordinates of the pole,then the polar of $(h,k)$ with respect to the circle

$$x^2+y^2-2ax=0$$

is

$$xh+yk-a(x+h)=0$$

or

$$y=x\left(-\frac{h}{k}+\frac{a}{k}\right)+\frac{ah}{k}\tag{1}$$

The equation of any tangent on the given parabola is

$$y=mx+\frac{a}{m}\tag{2}$$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ represent the same straight line,hence equating the coefficients,

$$m=\left(-\frac{h}{k}+\frac{a}{k}\right) \;\; \text{and} \;\; \frac{a}{m}=\frac{ah}{k}$$

Eliminate $m$ between the above two equations and locus of $(h,k)$ is $h^2+k^2=ah$.

Generalizing, we get the locus as $x^2+y^2=ax$.

---

My question is why equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ represent the same line? Equation $(1)$ is the polar of $(h,k)$ with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$ and equation $(2)$ is tangent to the parabola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following part of the question,

> the locus of the poles of $\left(\text{tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$}\right)$  with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2−2ax=0$

note that the $\left(\quad\right)$ part is **the polar** (with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$). (in other words, the question means that the tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is **the polar** with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax=0$.) (take a look at [polar](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html) in mathworld)

$(1)$ is the polar of the pole $(h,k)$ with respect to the circle $x^2+y^2−2ax=0$.

$(2)$ is the tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$.

So, from the question, we (can/have to) have $(1)=(2)$.